# Mysql Index on Table that gets deleted every night

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, indexing, query-optimization, amazon-rds

I am using mysql within Amazon RDS. I have a table **booking** with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `booking` (
   `id_by_customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `date_delivery` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `date_vat_effective` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `postingtext` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `amount` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `currency` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `vat` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `credit_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `debit_postingaccount_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `credit_postingaccount_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `tax_key` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `booking_number` double NOT NULL,
   `cost_location` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `circumstances_ll` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `transactions_purpose` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
   `receipts_assigned_invoice_numbers` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `receipts_assigned_counterparties` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `receipts_assigned_vat_rates` double NOT NULL,
   `receipts_assigned_assigned_amounts` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `receipts_assigned_assigned_dates` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `receipts_links` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `fixed` double NOT NULL,
   `comment` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `receipts_id_by_customer` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `transactions_id_by_customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_by_customer`),
   KEY `combined_index` (`debit_postingaccount_number`,`credit_type`,`credit_postingaccount_number`,`date`) USING BTREE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The table has less than 100k rows. Every night I delete all entries from the table and insert them again. I have a current query which runs for 20 minutes to get an output. I want to optimize this query (I have created the view susa_list for this):

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `admin`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `susa_list` AS
    (SELECT 
        `bookingOuter`.`debit_postingaccount_number` AS `account_id`,
        YEAR(`bookingOuter`.`date`) AS `booking_year`,
        (SELECT 
                SUM(`booking`.`amount`)
            FROM
                `booking`
            WHERE
                ((`booking`.`credit_type` = 'H')
                    AND (`booking`.`debit_postingaccount_number` = `bookingOuter`.`debit_postingaccount_number`)
                    AND (YEAR(`booking`.`date`) = YEAR(`bookingOuter`.`date`)))) AS `DEBIT_H`,
        (SELECT 
                SUM(`booking`.`amount`)
            FROM
                `booking`
            WHERE
                ((`booking`.`credit_type` = 'S')
                    AND (`booking`.`debit_postingaccount_number` = `bookingOuter`.`debit_postingaccount_number`)
                    AND (YEAR(`booking`.`date`) = YEAR(`bookingOuter`.`date`)))) AS `DEBIT_S`,
        (SELECT 
                SUM(`booking`.`amount`)
            FROM
                `booking`
            WHERE
                ((`booking`.`credit_type` = 'H')
                    AND (`booking`.`credit_postingaccount_number` = `bookingOuter`.`debit_postingaccount_number`)
                    AND (YEAR(`booking`.`date`) = YEAR(`bookingOuter`.`date`)))) AS `CREDIT_H`,
        (SELECT 
                SUM(`booking`.`amount`)
            FROM
                `booking`
            WHERE
                ((`booking`.`credit_type` = 'S')
                    AND (`booking`.`credit_postingaccount_number` = `bookingOuter`.`debit_postingaccount_number`)
                    AND (YEAR(`booking`.`date`) = YEAR(`bookingOuter`.`date`)))) AS `CREDIT_S`
    FROM
        `booking` `bookingOuter`
    GROUP BY `bookingOuter`.`debit_postingaccount_number` , `booking_year`)
```

My goal is to speed up the query

> select * from susa_list;

Should I rebuild the index every night? The data is only changing a little bit from night to night (and the values on the index columns are not changing).

I tried to create my own table susa_list_table before and run

```
create table susa_list_table as select * from susa_list
```

every night. However this query is already very slow and times out my AWS Lambda (Python) which is doing the import.

Any recommendations which speeds up the query are very welcome! :-)

Comment: Can i ask why you want to delete and insert them again every night?

Comment: Unclear -- The title implies deleting from the index (which is not possible), the text talks about deleting the rows of the table.  And it mentions "rebuilding the index".  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Ouch!

```
SUM(`booking`.`amount`)
`amount` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
```

Please don't `SUM` VARCHARs; all sorts of nasties can happen.

And, might the values be in different currencies?

Also, there is a `DATE` datatype.  (Also `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP`)

```
`date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
YEAR(`booking`.`date`)
```

I'm surprised that that function works!

Double??  `booking_number double NOT NULL,`

If there are locale issues, such as "thousands separator" and "timezone", deal with the *before* inserting into the table.

> Every night I delete all entries from the table and insert them again.

Why??

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  It may show that the composite index is not being used.  It *may* help to move `credit_type` to the start of that index.

In MySQL, BTree indexes do not degrade.  Do not re-index.

The `VIEW` can probably be written with a `CASE` so that you do only 1 select, not 5.